# webService REST with input in plain text

Tags: rest

I'm trying to do a server webservice in REST. My input is a string, but I don't know how to call it from URL (GET Example).

Below is my server.

```
  @PATH(/rest)
   @GET
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public void serverPlaintext(String input){
     System.out.prinln("Hello world");
    }
```

and here is what I tried to call in client.

[http://myserverip:port/WARname/rest?"myinput"](http://myserverip:port/WARname/rest?%22myinput%22)

Comment: Why the quotes in the query?

Comment: I tried with quotes and without quotes.. was just an example. I really dont know how to call it, anyway

Comment: You dont have to do that, everything you pass in via the url query is passed in as a string

Comment: ok, but anyway i couldnt call my server